# Partial safe area on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, safearealayoutguide

I have a page with a ListView that needs safe area padding so that the iPhone X bump doesn't clip the ListView content in landscape orientation. However, the bottom of the ListView doesn't need padding; the rounded bottom corners of the screen don't interfere.

The page enables safe area padding by calling this from the constructor:

```cs
Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.Page.SetUseSafeArea(On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>(), true);
```

How do I preserve safe area padding for all sides except the bottom? The solution has to work even if the user rotates the screen orientation while using the page.

Answer (score 1):

The safe area can be customized by retrieving its [Thickness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.thickness) value with the `Page.SafeAreaInsets` method from the [Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.platformconfiguration.iosspecific) namespace. It can then be modified as required and re-assigned to the Padding property in the page constructor or [OnAppearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing#Xamarin_Forms_Page_OnAppearing) override:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var safeInsets = On<iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
    safeInsets.Bottom = 0;
    safeInsets.Top = 35;
    safeInsets.Left = 35;
    safeInsets.Right = 35;
    Padding = safeInsets;
}
```

The effect of **Portrait** :

[image]

The effect of **Landscape** :

[image]

If you need to custom `SafeAreaInsets` when device orientation changes .There is a [OnSizeAllocated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows#reacting-to-changes-in-orientation) method can be used conveniently .

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    if (width != this.width || height != this.height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        if (width > height)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Landscape");
            var safeInsets = On<iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
            safeInsets.Bottom = 0;
            safeInsets.Top = 0;
            safeInsets.Left = 35;
            safeInsets.Right = 35;
            Padding = safeInsets;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Portrait");
            var safeInsets = On<iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
            safeInsets.Bottom = 0;
            safeInsets.Top = 35;
            safeInsets.Left = 0;
            safeInsets.Right = 0;
            Padding = safeInsets;
        }
    }
}
```

=================================Update================================

If need to fit as much more and more device ,you can make some phone model judgments (such as iPhone X) to set the size of the security area on their sides .In additiotn , you also can check whether contain Navigation Bar or Tab Bar to modify the size of `Thickness` . It should be the

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    if (width != this.width || height != this.height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        if (width > height)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Landscape");
            var safeInsets = On<iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
            // whether is iPhone X
            if (deveiceType.Equals("iPhone X"))
            {
                //whether contain Navigation Bar
                if (ContainNavigationBar) { safeInsets.Top = 44; } else { safeInsets.Top = 0; }
                //whether conatin Tab Bar
                if (ContainTabBar) { safeInsets.Bottom = 34; } else { safeInsets.Bottom = 0; }
            }
            safeInsets.Left = 35;
            safeInsets.Right = 35;
            Padding = safeInsets;
            Padding = safeInsets;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Portrait");
            var safeInsets = On<iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
            // whether is iPhone X
            if (deveiceType.Equals("iPhone X"))
            {
                //whether contain Navigation Bar
                if (ContainNavigationBar) { safeInsets.Top = 84; } else { safeInsets.Top = 44; }
                //whether conatin Tab Bar
                if (ContainTabBar) { safeInsets.Bottom = 34; }else{ safeInsets.Bottom = 0; }
            }
            safeInsets.Left = 0;
            safeInsets.Right = 0;
            Padding = safeInsets;
        }
    }
}
```

As long as Apple does not change the height of the status bar in the future, I don't think there will be problems with the heights set by hard coding.

Comment: The code samples show setting all 4 sides of the Thickness structs. Doesn't that defeat the purpose of calling SafeAreaInsets? Likewise for hard coding the inset sizes to 35, which work on iPhone X but not necessarily future phones?

Comment: @EdwardBrey Okey . First question , it not defeating the purpose of calling `SafeAreaInserts` .Because if only set one side (Bottom) ,the other sides will not preserve the safe area .Therefore , I set four sides to make it work . Second question ,due to Apple not supporting easy way to set `Thickness` for all devices even for future devices , I think you can make some iPhone model judgments (such as iPhone X) to set the size of the security area on their sides .I think this should be the best way to do now , will not affect future devices to show too much . I will update answer to exaplain it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to preserve insets that were never there. When using `SetUseSafeArea`, in portrait mode, there are normally no left and right insets. Likewise for top and bottom insets in landscape.

Comment: @EdwardBrey Yeah , that's the reason why setting four sides every time .